# Конвертер из JSX (React JS) в HTML + JS + CSS

Tags: reactjs

Существует проект ReactJS, мне нужно преобразовать его в статический веб-сайт HTML + JS + CSS. Как это сделать?

Я хочу перестроить приложения так, чтобы каждая внутренняя страница ReactJS представляла собой отдельный HTML-файл. Я могу открыть приложение через браузер и скопировать готовый html-код, но это не удобно. Может быть, для этого есть какой-то сервис / библиотека?

Comment: а смысл? проект на реакте подразумевает динамическое поведение. Как вы собираетесь динамику отобразить в статическом html?

Comment: Да, я хочу динамику отобразить в статическом html.